# Understanding jmeter results - Discrepancies

Tags: jmeter

I am doing performance testing for one of my applications.

Doing tests in Non-GUI mode.

I have one Jmeter master server and 3 slaves.

When I run the jmx file in the master server I also write the results to a .jtl file

```
./jmeter -n -t /home/ubuntu/bsc.jmx -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<master-ip> -R <slave-1-ip>,<slave-2-ip>,<slave-3-ip>  -l /home/ubuntu/bareresults.jtl
```

Now when I run the test the summary comes as follows (image attached)

[image]

According to my understanding, this shows that throughput is 1456.9/s.

But when I upload the bareresults.jtl in GUI (image attached) it shows throughput is 136.0/s

[image]

Why is it so? I am not able to find an exact explanation for this difference.

Edit: [Link to .jtl file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uu-3yU1N9xQ8qzLhGPKfa4AIoa5wOOIF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is really odd. Can you share your jtl?

Comment: Sure, added in the question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are several tests results in your file. Clean your file before each run - as easy as
   `>/home/ubuntu/bareresults.jtl`

Then results should be same